# Changing screen resolution on android devices without re booting

Tags: android, screen, resolution, reboot

I tried changing the screen resolution in build.prop file in system, but it requires re booting.
I need a solution for changing screen resolution on android devices without re booting.

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. Everytime when Android boots, it will read the build.prop file and set parameters pointed by it accordingly. After it has booted, it will not access that file dynamically to change parameters. So for any change to take effect, a reboot is compulsary, you cannot escape it.

Comment: Thanks Royston, for the reply. Is there any other way other than build.prop to achieve the same: changing screen resolution

Comment: No Krishna, thats the only way, you have taken the right approach, unfortunately Android is not like windows which changes display resolution dynamically. So you will have to live with this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

*Set resolution (e.g. 1024x768):*

```
$ am display-size 1024x768
```

*Reset:*

```
$ am display-size reset
```

Doesn't require a reboot. This works with Android 4.2. Solution for 4.3 is mentioned by [LiTTle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840118/changing-screen-resolution-on-android-devices-without-re-booting/19044723#19044723)

There is also an App for that called [NOMone Resolution Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MTMDevelopers.ScreenSpecs).

Answer (score 0):

Android **can** change the screen resolution.
I think that you need Android 4.0 and above version.
Only things you need is terminal emulator and root access. 
Reproduce the following steps:
1. Open the terminal emulator app.
2. Type `su`.
3. Type `wm`.
Read the help message appeared and you will understand...

In case you want an App take a look at [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.bits.phoneastablet&hl=en) on Play Store or the [source](https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/PhoneAsTablet) from Github.